# Fast way of looping through TFS WorkItems or anyway of bulk insert TFS work Items quickly to SQL

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-sdk

I have a requirement to fetch all work items from TFS and store every detail into SQL DB. I am able to take everything from TFS without much trouble. But not getting a perfect way for pushing these data into SQL Db. I thought about looping through the resulting object and push them individually, but its very time and resource consuming. So looking forward to a perfect clean solution.

Here is the code I am using

```
    public void  GetAllTfsWorkItems()
    {
        //List<string> projects = new List<string>();
        //projects = LoadProjectsList();
        var tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(_uri));
        var workitemstore = new WorkItemStore(tpc);
        Query query = new Query(workitemstore, "select * from workitems where  [System.WorkItemType] in ('Epic','Bug','Feature','Product Backlog Item','Task') ");
        WorkItemCollection wic = query.RunQuery();
        List<string> PE = new List<string>();
        List<string> fields = new List<string>();
        foreach(WorkItem wi in wic)
        {
            PE.Add(wi.Title);
            var parentlink = wi.WorkItemLinks.Cast<WorkItemLink>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.LinkTypeEnd.Name == "Parent");
            WorkItem parentworkitem = null;
            int parentid;

            if(parentlink!=null)
            {
                parentid = parentlink.TargetId;
                //parentworkitem = workitemstore.GetWorkItem(parentlink.TargetId);

            }
        }

    }



public class TfsWorkItems
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string WorkItemType { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string AreaPath { get; set; }
    public string AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public string BoardColumn { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string IterationPath { get; set; }
    public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public string AcceptanceCriteria { get; set; }
    public string BusinessValue { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public string Effort    { get; set; }
    public string PCode { get; set; }
    public string Parent { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public string DomainName { get; set; }
}
```

The loop takes around 10-15 mins to finish. But I expect some easier solution there like the direct mapping of WorkItem array object into to my custom class TFSWorkItems and some method to push the data together. Please suggest an easier solution. deadline is reaching badly because I guess time running very fast in 2019.

**Please note there are around 250k+ items in TFS**

Comment: Please note there are around 200k+ work items there in TFS